# Is there a version of Indicator-Remindor for 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation

I'd like to use [Indicator-Remindor](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/indicator-remindor/), but it doesn't seem to be available for 14.04, at least not in the Software Centre. Is it available somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indicator-Remindor has an official PPA, you can add it to your system by executing the following commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bhdouglass/indicator-remindor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-remindor
```

or by adding the following lines with the editor of your chice to your sources list file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` (remember to edit it as root)

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/bhdouglass/indicator-remindor/ubuntu trusty main 
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/bhdouglass/indicator-remindor/ubuntu trusty main
```

Source: https://launchpad.net/~bhdouglass/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-remindor

Comment: Thanks! I can't upvote, though - not enough rep.

Comment: I couldn't even post comments two hours ago :) Glad to know it works